# Unexpected junk after else statement: (i == 1 .AND. 1 < j < L)

Tags: if-statement, fortran, fortran90

I'm trying to write a program which contains a lot of else if statements. However, I cannot understand where this error is coming from. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the if block I currently have:

```
    if (i == 1 .AND. j==1) then
        E = E + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j+1) + A(L,j) + A(i,L)

    else if (i == 1 .AND. j==L) then
        E = E + A(i,j-1) + A(i+1,j) + A(i,1) + A(L,j)

    else if (i == L .AND. j == 1) then
        E = E + A(i,j+1) + A(i-1,j) + A(1,j) + A(i,L)

    else if (i == L .AND. j == L) then
        E = E + A(i,j-1) + A(i-1,j) + A(1,j) + A(i,1)

    else if (i == 1 .AND. 1 < j < L) then
        E = E + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j+1) + A(i,j-1) + A(L,j)

    else if (i == L .AND. 1 < j < L) then
        E = E + A(i-1,j) + A(i,j+1) + A(i,j-1) + A(1,j)

    else if (1 < i < L .AND. j == 1) then
        E = E + A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j+1) + A(i,L)

    else if (1 < i < L .AND. j == L) then
        E = E + A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j-1) + A(i,1)
    else
        E = E + A(i-1,j) + A(i+1,j) + A(i,j-1) + A(i,j+1)
    end if
```

The error that keeps coming up is:

```
Ising.f90:56:15:

     else if (i == 1 .AND. 1 < j < L) then
           1
Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)
Ising.f90:59:15:

     else if (i == L .AND. 1 < j < L) then
           1
Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)
Ising.f90:62:15:

     else if (1 < i < L .AND. j == 1) then
             1
Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)
Ising.f90:65:15:

     else if (1 < i < L .AND. j == L) then
           1
Error: Unexpected junk after ELSE statement at (1)
```

Comment: Even if you use an extension which accepts comparison between logical and integer it doesn't do what you think. If you mean 1<j .And.  j<L you could fix it.  Turning off that weird extension should be among effects of ifort -standard-semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use expressions like `1 < i < L` to determine if `i` falls within the range 1 to L.
You need to use the intersection of two inequality tests. Use something like

`else if (1 < i .AND. i < L .AND. j == L) then`

Comment: This would be a bit easier on the eyes with SELECTED CASE, or WHERE and ELSEWHERE . Or making I if structure and thenputting the j testing within it.

Comment: Or, given it looks like periodic boundary conditions, make the i and j loops which are almost certainly there go from 2 to j and set the exceptional cases outside the loop, just avoiding the if/case/whatever all together

Answer (score 0):

@VladimirF Well as I mentioned it looks like some interpolation...

@Ianbush also mentioned some good points.

maybe... It is some smoother/interpolator?

Smoother example:

```
L = UBOUND(OldThing, 1)   !assumes it is square!
ALLOCATE(newthing(0:L+1, 0:L+1) )
DO I = 1, L
  DO J = 1, L
    NewThing(I,j) = OldThing(I,j)
  ENDDO 
ENDDO

! Probably a derivative to extrapolate the outliers is better...
! Kindergarten example below is for simplicity. 
DO I= 1, L
  NewThing(0,(I))= OldThing(1,I)
  NewThing(0,(I))= OldThing(1,I)
  NewThing(0,(I))= OldThing(1,I)
  NewThing(0,(I))= OldThing(1,I)
ENDDO

NewThing(0  ,  0) = OldThing(1,1)
NewThing(0,  L+1) = OldThing(1,L)
NewThing(L+1,  0) = OldThing(L,1)
NewThing(L+1,L+1) = OldThing(L,L)

!then one is always within the bounds... And the normal case is executed.
E = E + NewThing(I-1,j) + NewThing(i+1,j) + NewThing(i,j-1) + NewThing(i,j+1)
```

Probably a return of NewThing(1:L,1:L) needs to happen

Comment: Please don't post new answers as a reaction, you can edit the present one if it about the same topic. And your usage of `WHERE` is very strange. `WHERE` is for **array** expressions.

Answer (score -1):

This would be a bit easier on the eyes with SELECTED CASE, or WHERE and ELSEWHERE . Or making I if structure and thenputting the j testing within it.

Without seeing the rest of code I can only guess that this could be similar to some interpolation...

Something where one could do this on a single math statement line if the array was indiexed from (0:n+1).

Comment: How does this answer the question about the error? Is it meant to be a comment? How would you rewrite that using WHERE? I have spent quite some time looking at that and I still have no idea. How can you even know that the result is assigned to some array?